# MacBook Pro Erase All Contents and Settings

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, monterey, apple-silicon, ventura

Does performing `Erase All Contents and Settings` as they described [here](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT212749) 3 times in a short period of time have any adverse effect on the Mac?

Specs: MacBook Pro, 2021, M1 Pro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than erasing and writing data to the drive and potentially losing your data if you haven’t backed it up, there is no adverse effect on your Mac.